# SQL JOIN of 2 tables members and people

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    gender VARCHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE relations (
    c_id INT,
    p_id INT
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES(145, 'HAWBAKER' , 'F');
INSERT INTO relations VALUES(145, 202);
INSERT INTO relations VALUES(145, 107);

INSERT INTO people VALUES(202, 'Blackston' , 'F');
INSERT INTO people VALUES(107, 'Days' , 'M');

SELECT * FROM people;
SELECT * FROM relations;
```

The output of the child consists of the given 3 fields: child, father, mother

Write a query that prints the name of a child and his parents in indivisual columns respectively in order of the name of the child

i have done this :

```
SELECT p.name, r.p_id
FROM people p JOIN relations r 
ON ( r.c_id = p.id);
```

Comment: You will need to open/join `people` table **twice** with different aliases.

Comment: can you write query i am beginner in sql

Comment: If you do not want to write your own query, then search the web. There will be a ton of family (parent - child) and company (employee - manager) queries.

Comment: You are a beginner and this looks like homework. If you want to learn sql, try something better and then ask for help